# VBA can't enter break mode after running external DLL

Tags: vba, excel, dll

I wrote a DLL, and use some of it's functions in Excel VBA. I inserted a breakpoint the line after the call to the DLL. When it gets there, I get the error "Can't enter break mode at this time". The code is:

```
Public tester As Finance.Root

Sub testing()
   Set tester = New Finance.Root
   Set aa = Sheets(1).Range("A1")
   Call tester.startUp(aa)
   MsgBox ("HI")
End Sub
```

The first part of the DLL that is being called is:

```
Sub startUp(excelLink)
   Set MB = excelLink.Application.ActiveWorkbook
   Set oExcel = excelLink.Application
   oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
   Call fillGlobals
   MB.Sheets.Add Type:=appPath & "\scripts\TestGLPage.xls"
   Set HP = MB.Sheets("Home Page")
   For Each sht In MB.Sheets
       If sht.Name <> HP.Name Then sht.Delete
   Next sht
   WhichGL.Show 1
End Sub
```

Edit: I added a msgbox after running the DLL (see updated code), and the message box does pop up. After the message box, I get the error message "can't enter break mode". This leads me to believe that it has nothing to do with running the DLL. Any other reason I would get that error message?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It might help if we knew what dll you're speaking of.

Comment: are you sure execution has returned from the dll? Can you hook up Visual Studio debugger to the Excel Application instance and track the call through the dll? Just clutching at straws ;)

Comment: I did that. It runs until the last End Sub of the DLL, and then I get the error message

Comment: I added a msgbox after running the DLL (see updated code), and the message box does pop up. After the message box, I get the error message "can't enter break mode". This leads me to believe that it has nothing to do with running the DLL. Any other reason I would get that error message?

Comment: Rolling your own `dll` can land you in some lonely places.  That said, you might try setting `Options -> General -> Error Trapping` to "Break on class errors" in the VBA editor.

Comment: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=46214

Comment: Smandoli: I have that set already.

Answer (score 0):

What it is seems (after googling for a while) is that I can't enter break mode due to the fact that the DLL deletes sheets during execution. Seems that deleting sheets is a cause for not being to enter break mode. Nobody seems to explain the reason for this.

I would love if someone had a workaround for this. I add and delete sheets as part of a large project.